# Word meaning of "trial"

Tags: meaning, definition

In [The Economist: As face-recognition technology spreads, so do ideas for subverting it](https://www.economist.com/science-and-technology/2019/08/15/as-face-recognition-technology-spreads-so-do-ideas-for-subverting-it):

> And a number of British police forces have tested the technology (face-recognition) as a tool of mass surveillance in **trials** designed to spot criminals on the street.

What is the meaning of the word **trial**?

My understanding is **experiment** but it seems that the meaning duplicates with the word **test**. Now I'm confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, a trial is a test (in particular, a test for a limited period of time). British police forces have tested facial recognition technology for periods of time to determine whether they can recognise criminals on the street.

Per the [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trial), "a test, usually over a limited period of time, to discover how effective or suitable something or someone is".

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your quoting it means **attempt** or **effort**.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer.